# Where to store UUID in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, uuid

I'm new to android development  , I want to make my app non shareable, so I use UUID.

The problem is where to store it ?
I tried **Shared Preferences** and writing it to **internal storage**.

But when I share the app, Shared preferences is cleared and the file doesn't exist in the app on the other phone,  so i can't compare UUID's ,any ideas?

Comment: You can't stop someone from being able to install your app.  Your method won't work at all, because a fresh install wouldn't have any shared preferences with it.  If you want to do this, make the user authenticate with a server.  That will prevent them from getting into the app.  That's about all you can do, there's no other way for the app to know how it was installed.

Comment: I guess firebase can handle it ? @GabeSechan

Comment: Exactly how is that supposed to help?  Think it through-  you install the app on a new device-  how does that work?  And how does that differ from it being shared (answer:  it doesn't).  There's no way to authenticate the device in a world where you're running on people's devices and not your own.  So all you can do is authenticate the user-  a login system against a server (now the login data could be in firebase, although I wouldn't suggest it).

Comment: Yea you're right , I'll speak with the team leader about it  , i hope i be experienced like u one day... many thanks :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a unique device id from android using this function

```
Settings.Secure.getString(activity.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

This will return a unique device id & you can use it to do whatever you wish to do. But yeah do check for nullability as well. Most of the time it works well but yeah sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Yea i understand you  , I'm trying to figure out where to store this ID somewhere permanently so my app can compare it if the user tried to install it somewhere else

Comment: you don't need to store it, this will always give you same unique id... even after app installs

Comment: just to clarify... you want to check for same unique id on a particular device after app reinstall ... correct ??

Comment: Yea ur right ..

Comment: If you find it helpful, kindly accept & upvote the answer thanks :)